# Getting 1-min historical data (suds object) from BarChart API data into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, suds

I've been searching around and haven't found what seems like an easy task to get historical data from the BarChart API into a Pandas dataframe with the index set as the time stamp. Here's a few records of 1-minute data. Anyone know an easy way to get this into a dataframe? Much appreciated.

Here is what is returned when doing a query on (3) records for ESZ20 (e-mini SP500 dec), I am using a wsdl suds client to get this data. When I print the type, I get this: <class 'suds.sudsobject.getHistoryArray'>

```
(getHistoryArray){
   getHistoryItem[] = 
      (getHistoryItem){
         symbol = "ESZ20"
         timestamp = 2020-12-03 23:57:00-06:00
         tradingDay = 2020-12-04
         open = 3674.0
         high = 3675.5
         low = 3674.0
         close = 3674.75
         volume = 357
      },
      (getHistoryItem){
         symbol = "ESZ20"
         timestamp = 2020-12-03 23:58:00-06:00
         tradingDay = 2020-12-04
         open = 3674.75
         high = 3674.75
         low = 3674.25
         close = 3674.25
         volume = 125
      },
      (getHistoryItem){
         symbol = "ESZ20"
         timestamp = 2020-12-03 23:59:00-06:00
         tradingDay = 2020-12-04
         open = 3674.25
         high = 3674.25
         low = 3674.0
         close = 3674.0
         volume = 189
      },
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this response to a similar question [python api response to json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031256/python-api-response-to-json-object/65082581?noredirect=1#comment115065956_65082581)

I use barchart api calls like this, but if you need to use your current method refer to link provided for some guidance.

```
url = 'https://marketdata.websol.barchart.com/getHistory.json?\
apikey=apikeyhere&splits=True&symbol=AAPL&type=daily&\
startDate=20100101&maxRecords=5000&order=asc'

myResponse = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(myResponse.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data['results'])
```